# Setting a Static IP Running FreeBSD8 in VirtualBox hosted on Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, static-ip

I'm using VirtualBox on Windows 7 (host) to run a FreeBSD (guest) based web server.  I`ve assigned a static ip of 192.168.80. 1 to the (virtualized) NIC which is run in bridged mode.  The problem is that when I ping an external server (such as google.com) I get a No route to host error:

```
dimetro# ping google.com
PING google.com (66.249.90.104): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
...
```

I can ping the BSD server from both another virtualized machine and my host machine and from the server, I can ping everything on the network.  The router ip is 192.168.1.1/16.

ADDENDUM:
I have the following lines in /etc/rc.conf on the BSD VM to configure networking:

```
defaultrouter="192.168.1.1"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.80.1 netmask 255.255.0.0"
```

Comment: What is your IP configuration for the FreeBSD VM?  Specifically, what is the default gateway and netmask set to?

Comment: I've edited my question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I didn't add the domain of the BSD VM to /etc/hosts.  What I don't understand is why I need to.  If I configured the NIC using dhclient, I don't need to specify the host in /etc/hosts.

Comment: I don't see why that should matter, either, for the problem you described.  Should you have a similar problem in the future, `netstat -rn` will display the routing table, which will help with the diagnosis.

Comment: dhclient will set the hostname using the response from the dhcp server.